# Navigating to other screens not working with programmatic routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a `Routes` component that returns `Stack.Screen` routes based on `user` state, or a loading screen depending on a `loading` state coming from a context.

For some reason when calling `navigation.nagivate` to change screens, it just redirects back to whatever the `initialRouteName` was.

I suspect it's because the loader isn't returning any routes and the `navigation.navigate` call is lost somewhere, but I'm unsure.

MVCE https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-glitter-b8w5j?file=/src/App.js

Routes.js

```
function Routes() {
  const { loading } = useContext(AppContext);
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (loading) {
    return <Text>Loading</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {user ? (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Order" component={OrderScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

OrderScreen.js (The route in question that won't work)

```
function OrderScreen({ order_id }) {
  const { order, getOrder } = useContext(OrderContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    getOrder(order_id);
  });
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Order</Text>
      <Text>{order}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

OrderProvider.js (where `getOrder` is called from)

```
const OrderContext = createContext({});
function OrderProvider({ children }) {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState(null);
  const { setLoading } = useContext(AppContext);
  return (
    <OrderContext.Provider
      value={{
        order,
        setOrder,
        getOrder: (orderId) => {
          setLoading(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setOrder(orderId);
            setLoading(false);
          }, 1000);
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </OrderContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with navigation is with the 'loading' state that you have in the context.

So when you open the Order screen you set the loading to true in the AppContext which causes the NavigationContainer in routes to re render which resets the navigation state.

```
const OrderContext = createContext({});
function OrderProvider({ children }) {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState(null);
  const [orderLoading, setOrderLoading] = useState(false);
  const { setLoading } = useContext(AppContext);
  return (
    <OrderContext.Provider
      value={{
        order,
        setOrder,
        orderLoading,
        getOrder: (orderId) => {
          setOrderLoading(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setOrder(orderId);
            setOrderLoading(false);
          }, 1000);
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </OrderContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

You will have to have a loading in the order context which will solve this issue. And re rendering the whole navigation container is not a good idea.

The snack has a working example which has a loading only for the order screen

https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/9be728

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is there no way to keep the global loading state rather than having an identical loading mechanism for each screen?

Comment: Maybe have a Modal and display it on top, because one you re render the NavigationContainer it will lose the state, Still its like re rendering the whole app to load items each time which is not something that I would recommend

Comment: @BenFortune That would be a use for a higher order class, where the higher order class renders the loader if required and otherwise renders the child.